# Mavic Pro - Microsoft Build 2018 Windows SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I am looking for some purchasing assistance. I have tried registering on the DJI Forums as well as the DEV forums but I cannot seem to post anything anywhere. I have emailed DJI but I have not yet received any response from them.

I recently watched the Microsoft build conference 2018 vision Keynote. I was fascinated with the presentation about the Windows sdk and the Mavic air. So much so that I want to buy a drone. The video is available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EruH-4Fvecc (watch from around 3:30)

I want to buy myself a drone and I fell in love with the Mavic Pro. I would just love to get some info on one or two things.

1. The demo at the conference was done using a Mavic Air drone. Will I be able to do the same on a Mavic Pro using the new Windows SDK?
2. I am interested in the live video feed and processing of that feed as it was demonstrated. I believe this has something to do with IOT edge. Again, will I be able to do this on a Mavic Pro?
3. I don't see the sdk available on the dev site. I saw the guidance sdk but I believe this is something else and not the same sdk which DJI is currently working on with Microsoft. Any idea when this will officially launch?

I want to ensure I buy the correct drone to fit my needs. It would be a lot of money to spend only to find out later that I cannot do with it what I intend to. Information on this subject is very scarce online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. Mavic Pro will be covered in the final release of WindowsSDK.
2. Live video feed is a standard feature provided by the SDK. The IoT Edge stack consumes the feed and runs additional software (in the case of the demo, the AI stack that detects the damages)
3. The WindowsSDK is currently given as an exclusivity to Build attendees. It will later be released to the rest of DJI developer community (early June) through developer.dji.com. The final release is for the end of 2018.

Source: I run developer technologies at DJI.

Comment: I attended build, but did not get info on the SDK. Is there somewhere that I can get access? I didn't own a drone until after getting the Air in the Search and Rescue challenge

Comment: You should have received an email with instructions on the Tuesday of the event. Check your spam box maybe?

Comment: Thanks Arnaud - I had missed that link

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is now downloadable (since end of Oktober, beginning of November 2018?) from https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/

Only needs a DJI account, I think, which you should have (and might need anyway) when you fly any DJI drone.